# Check if char array contains digits

Tags: c++

So I have a random char array, i.e "asdd1vnb24vnf63vbn,-5h-2kk", and I should check if it contains digits, and if it does, my task is to add them with opposite signs (S=-1-2-4-6-3+5+2) **without using string functions**.
But for now I'm stuck here and simply cannot understand why it doesn't work and "Sum" gives random numbers, though it is able to print digits in an array.

```
int main ()
{
     char s [] = "asdd1vnb24vnf63vbn,-5h-2kk";
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); i++) {
         if (isdigit(s[i]) !=0) {
              sum += s[i];
              cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;
         }
     }
     system ("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You're adding the character codes rather than the values of the digits, and you're not alternating the sign.

Comment: Minor nit: `sizeof(s[0])` is always 1 when `s` is an array of `char`.

Comment: Another minor nit: `if (isdigit(s[i]) != 0)` can also be written as `if (isdigit(s[i])`. The latter conveys the meaning a bit better.

Comment: Once again relevant: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Comment: What answer are you expecting for that input?  Is it `-3`?

Comment: `s[i] - '0'` will give you the value of the digit.

Comment: @PeteBecker Actually I don't find that to be a bad thing. Magic numbers are bad and `sizeof(s[0])` is self-documenting (and it changes with `s` if needs be). The real nit is using this dangerous array-size-finding "trick" in the first place instead of something type-safe like `std::size`

Answer (score 3):

you add the ASCII value to sum variable not the integer value
only need little correction in your code in `sum += s[i]` to `sum += s[i] - '0'`

Comment: Note that these not necessarily have to be _ASCII values_.

Answer (score 1):

You should add not `s[i]`, instead it should be `s[i] - '0'`. 
Why?

- `s[i]` is a char code, for 'zero' it could be 48, then 49 for 'one', 50 for 'two' and so on. So, you increment ascii code value instead of char value
- Once you decrement `s[i]` with '0' char, you receive exact digit value (in case it is really a digit, because we don't see your `isdigit` implementation)

Comment: _"it could be 48"_ that would be true for ASCII character sets only.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, absolutely, see the note in braces above

Comment: Your note in braces above doesn't address that. Furthermore, they are parentheses not braces. Also `isdigit` is standard.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious `sum += s[i] - '0'` I see another problem - topic starter wont to inverse digits sign. So you need to check  preceding '-' key:

```
 if (isdigit(s[i])) {
     if (i > 0 && s[i - 1] == '-')
        sum += s[i] - '0';
     else
        sum -= s[i] - '0';
```

Comment: Correct, although I got the impression the OP was saving that until later and just wanted help with the bit they'd got to so far (which is reasonable) _"But for now I'm stuck here"_ Divide and conquer is great to see in a student and should be encouraged :)

Answer (score 1):

> my task is to add them with opposite signs

If that's the case, in addition to the advice given in the other answers, you need to keep track of the polarity of the sign, whether it is negative or positive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    char ptr[] = "asdd1vnb24vnf63vbn,-5h-2kk";
    int multiplier = 1; // this starts out at 1
    char *p = ptr;
    int value = 0;
    while ( *p )  // keep going until the end of the string
    { 
      if (isdigit(*p))
      { 
         value += multiplier * (*p - '0');
         multiplier *= -1;  // switch polarity
      }
      ++p;
    }
    std::cout << value;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f81f4fbf0f904467)

Comment: This is a very C-like way to iterate an array. We can do without the pointers for something much more expressive.